# How handle Uncaught Error : Class not found PHP / Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm beginning a project with oop as beginner and I'm trying to use some classes that I think are recognized by vscode and composer because when I click on their namespaces it lead me to right class but when I run the code in the browser I have fatal error telling me that my class is not found.

I try many things :

- Delete the vendor folder and install it again
- Changing the case of my namespaces they was all in lowercase then I read that I had to start them with the first letter in uppercase (Nothing has change)
- I checked the path of these folders and everything is fine regardless to the realpath built-in function of php
- I update my modification on the composer.json with the composer-dump-autoload command nothing change

I don't really know where I messed up :

[image: Project Folder Structure]

Its the index.php file (in the public folder) :
[image]

The database.php file :

[image]

The article.php file :
[image]

And finally my composer.json :

[image]

I don't know if its useful to say it but when I try to make a require of my model  file in the index.php file its working but as I removed the require its not longer working

Comment: My bad I found the solution my self it was tied to the wrong path on the composer.json file

Comment: Create an answer of it. And for most class loading problems, it is the wrong path the one way or another. (hint: post code next to screenshots, this is more hepful for future visitors).

Comment: Please don't post code hidden in screenshots. Always share text content in text form

Comment: Ok sorry , I'll be more precise and formal next time (I'm not used to post a lot there)

Comment: @Yokke: This website has an [edit] functionality which you can use already today for this Q&A entry. You might otherwise see downvotes. And its less of a formality, its just because this website is text based. You can have the joy of pictures, but see it as an extra.

Comment: @hakre: Ok so I have to be more specific on what I've done and want to achieve and use pictures only when required. Got it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution it was related to the path that I set on composer.json my classes with the namespace "Articles" wasn't able to load correctly even if vscode can read it only because I haven't wrote the relative path like I should the "src" folder was on root but I've gone up too far on my directory that why it wasn't working so I just removed the dots and everything works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).